# How to get date from the filename

Tags: java, date

I'm writing a program to generate a report based on the date range entered by the user.I have to read some zip files which contain the date in the mm/dd format.The problem is user should enter the date in mm/dd/yyyy format and compare the dates present in the files
The year part is mentioned in the file name i.e.20120228.log contains the data for the year 2012.

How do I get this year part from all the files to compare with the date entered by the user?

Please help me on this

Comment: I tried storing the individual file names with getName() in a string and when I displayed it I got the file name as H--RAINTREE-PARKER94-/20120228.log. How do I split it to get the year part from it?

Comment: You mean you have a problem extracting the first four characters out of a string? Because that's how your question reads right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html

This will help you. Use a regular expression to split the string.
Once you have the date in this format: 20120228 you can easily find the date from it.